# RegEx ActionScript 3

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I am trying to figure out a regex to strip extra single quotes so that I would end up with only one single quote. To explain my question better, here is an example.

Let's say I have 3 different strings such as this ones.

(two single quotes)

```
Name<span fontSize=''16'' baselineShift=''superscript''>ABC</span>
```

(three single quotes)

```
Name<span fontSize='''16''' baselineShift='''superscript'''>ABC</span>
```

(four single quotes)

```
Name<span fontSize=''''16'''' baselineShift=''''superscript''''>ABC</span>
```

I am trying to sanitize the string to end up with this:

```
Name<span fontSize='16' baselineShift='superscript'>ABC</span>
```

I tried several online tools. This one is my favourite one: http://ryanswanson.com/regexp/#start. But I just can't get it right.

Could someone please help me out? Any tips and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `'+`?

```
var str:String = "Name<span fontSize=''''16'''' baselineShift=''''superscript''''>ABC</span>";
trace( str.replace(/'+/g, "'") );
```

Comment: I am just slapping my forehead right now. :) Thank so much, Marty!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the docs for AS3's RegEx code? [AS3 Replace](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace%28%29)
You could try something like this

```
var myPattern:RegExp = /'{2,100}/g;  
var str:String = "fontSize=''''16''''";
trace(str.replace(myPattern, "'"));
```

The '{2,100} essentially looks for a match of ' that occurs between 2 - 100 times and replaces it with a single '.

Comment: What if there are 101?

Comment: Then you really need to reconsider how your program is generating the ' :)